# How to PIVOT columns based on the date

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE region (
    region_name  VARCHAR2(255),
    region_date  DATE
);

INSERT INTO region VALUES('Paris','23-01-15');
INSERT INTO region VALUES('Paris','28-01-15');
INSERT INTO region VALUES('France','23-01-16');
INSERT INTO region VALUES('France','22-07-17');
INSERT INTO region VALUES('France','21-01-17');
INSERT INTO region VALUES('Germany','25-01-18');

COMMIT;
```

I need a `SELECT` query where I would require `DISTINCT region_name` and based on the `region_date`. `SELECT` query should have 5 columns as `region_name` `year_1` `year_2` `year_3` `year_4` wherein `year_1` is 2015 `year_2` is 2016 and so on. Based on the `region_name` I need a `COUNT` for the `region_date` that how many regions fall in the same year. Below is my expected result

| REGION_NAME | Year_1 | Year_2 | Year_3 | Year_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paris | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| France | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Germany | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

For Paris - for Year_1 - It has 2 records so the count is 2 for year_1 and for rest it is 0.
Likewise, for all. I am wondering if this can be done.

Note: I have to restrict the report till the year 2018 only. If anything comes after 2018 then that will be included in the report

Tool used: SQL Developer(18c)

Comment: Would there always be only 4 years in your expected report?

Comment: No, I have to restrict till the year 2018 only. If anything beyond 2018 that will not be included in the report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pivot to do so:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 CREATE TABLE region (
     region_name  VARCHAR2(255),
     region_date  DATE
 );

 INSERT INTO region VALUES('Paris','23-JAN-15');
 INSERT INTO region VALUES('Paris','28-JAN-15');

 INSERT INTO region VALUES('France','23-JAN-16');
 INSERT INTO region VALUES('France','22-JUL-17');
 INSERT INTO region VALUES('France','21-JAN-17');
 INSERT INTO region VALUES('Germany','25-JAN-18');
```

Query:

```
  select * from
  (SELECT region_name, extract(year from region_date)yr FROM region )
  pivot
  (
  COUNT(*) for yr  in (2015,2016,2017,2018)
  )
```

Output:

| REGION_NAME | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paris | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| France | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Germany | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=dc36d500b3855af322610f45d13e68bb)*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a fixed 4 years in the result set, we can try the following pivot query:

```sql
SELECT
    region_name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM region_date) = 2015 THEN 1 END) AS Year_1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM region_date) = 2016 THEN 1 END) AS Year_2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM region_date) = 2017 THEN 1 END) AS Year_3,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM region_date) = 2018 THEN 1 END) AS Year_4
GROUP BY
    region_name;
```